# Windows Forms - How to get a verticalscroll bar for a listbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

The scrolbar from my listbox is horizontal but I need it to be vertical. I cannot find it in the properties.

Does anyone know how to do that or did I looked wrong in the properties?

The project is in Windows Forms

Answer (score 0):

It should show when some rows become invisible. If you want to see it all the time set property **ScrollAlwaysVisible** to true

Answer (score 0):

To have a single-column `ListBox` with vertical scrollbar:

- Set `MultiColumn` to `false`

To have a multi-column `ListBox` with horizontal scrollbar:

- Set `MultiColumn` to `true`
- Set `ColumnWidth` to adjust width of columns